# Is a Random integer random in all bases?

Tags: random-generation

Suppose you generate a random integer, by generating random digits U(0,B) in base B, and concatenating the resulting digits. To get a baseB number, *N* of length L, say.

Then you consider the string *L_a* representing the same number in base A.

Are the non-leading digits of *L_a* going to be random U(0,A)?

(I assume we'll get some weird factors for the leading digit, based on the upper bounds of the numbers in the respective bases, and perhaps Benford's law. Hence excluding that digit.)

Comment: Do you mean the computer representation of a number with a finite number of digits? Or a true number with an infinite number of digits? In the first case, the truncation may differ  from one base to the next.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was thinking about integers, not ... *baseB*imals?

Comment: Please clarify (by an edit) in the main post that you were asking about integers. close votes maybe because unclear if question is about practical algorithms or is pure!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen ... I had already editted my post to clarify that ... 15 minutes before you posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in general **no**. It is easy to see that by writing out a small example, where the frequencies from the table are the exact probabilities. In the table below, we start with generating integers from $0,1,\dotsc,7$ in base two by randomly, independently generating bits, then convert to the other bases:

```
Binary Base-10  Base-3 Base-5 Base-7
000     0       00     00     00
001     1       01     01     01
010     2       02     02     02
011     3       10     03     03
100     4       11     04     04
101     5       12     10     05
110     6       20     11     06
111     7       21     12     10
```

while the individual bits are uniform (by construction) in base 2, none of the digits are uniform in the other bases. Note that in my example all the bases are relatively prime, that hints at where to go to search for examples where your claim is true ...

Comment: One would not generally use digit-wise transliteration, which is by itself a structured encoding, to convert between bases, and if one does, that structure is a property of the encoding, and says nothing about whether the encoded object is random or not. For example, $\pi$ will be random in any base, its digit-wise transliteration, e.g., from decimal to binary, will not be.

Comment: @Carl: That is true, but I read the question as about a digit-wise transliteration ...

Comment: Agreed. However, the answer is somewhat irrelevant as the encoding alone can be decrypted in the relative prime base case but not the random number from which it arose. So the answer does not appear to be random, but still is. Did we learn anything from this? Is this statistics, or is it an exercise in futility?

Comment: @Carl: Its just a quiz, I think. It is not useful other than as an exercise, more in primes than in statistics!

Comment: Agreed. I think it is off topic for this site but will not vote to close since you got some rep from it, more (prime) power to you.